# dynamic, with dependence polygon - svg in html5

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to create polygon as a background for menu ([please see this attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq0x2.png)), which should scale (responsive design).

Do i need to listen for size changes and change the points for main_menue_polygon polygon element with javascript? Maybe there is a better, more clean implementation with css?

Please note, that i will use bootstrap. Menu should start about 50px left of and end 50px right of the bootstrap main container.

```
<div style="width: 1138px; height: 555px">
    <img src="example-picture1.jpg"
</div>

<svg width="1300" height="200" id="main_menue_svg">
    <polygon id="main_menue_polygon" points="0,0 33,33 0,66 1244,66 1211,33 1244,0 0,0"
    style="fill:rgb(51, 76, 25);stroke:rgb(51, 76, 25);stroke-width:0;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bounding box to set the svg's width/height and viewBox. The example below uses your polygon,, and responds to window size and resize.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Resize Polygon</title>
</head>

<body>
<svg style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;' >
    <polygon id="main_menue_polygon" points="0,0 33,33 0,66 1244,66 1211,33 1244,0 0,0"
    style="fill:rgb(51, 76, 25);stroke:rgb(51, 76, 25);stroke-width:0;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>

<script>
//--onload, onresize----
function resizePolygon()
{
    var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
    var svgW=window.innerWidth
    var svgH=window.innerHeight
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x//-300
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height

        mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",bbx+" "+bby+" "+bbw+" "+bbh )
        mySVG.setAttribute("width",svgW)
        mySVG.setAttribute("height",svgH)
}
resizePolygon(); //---init window---
document.addEventListener("onload",resizePolygon(),false)
window.onresize=resizePolygon</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the height should not scale and the size should depende on bootstrap container size. It is about max 1140 and scale down if the window is smaller...